# The delete button in activeadmin does not work, and send me to the show

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

The problem is that I can not delete anything from my application.
I delete the views leaving only the public, the layout and admin.

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this?" href="/admin/actividades/34">Delete Actividade</a>
```

app/admin/actividades

```
ActiveAdmin.register Actividade do
menu :label => "Actividades", :priority => 14

form :partial => "form"
actions :index, :show, :new, :create, :update, :edit, :destroy
index :title => "Actividades" do 
    column "Id", :id
    column "Nome",  :name
    column "Grupo", :grupo
    column "Actividade", :category
    column "Nome da imagem",  :image_file_name
    column "Video",  :video
    column "Criado a",  :created_at
    column "Atualizada a",  :updated_at
    default_actions

end
```

end

Answer (score 5):

Check your active_admin.js file, must have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: check if jquery is loaded with the chrome inspector (or other)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me (i had old 1.5.1 version in my assets but I think you can replace it with any you want)

```
//= require jquery-1.5.1-min
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

Answer (score 0):

In the active_admin.js.coffee.

Try:

```
#= require active_admin/base
```